# Define A Variable By Calling Page Content

Tags: php, variables, buffering

On my php buffering page, I am able to create and define a variable by using the contents of my form field, like this...

PHP:

```
<?php $data = $_POST['data']; ?>
```

And in my form, I am able to create the 'value' of the 'data' field by using php 'include' to call in the data from 'data_page.php' like this...

FORM:

```
<input name="data" type="text" value="<?php include "data_page.php";?>">
```

This process does work, however... I would like to bypass the form part of the process and still create that same variable.

I have tried a few ways to do this, including this...

```
<?php $data = $_REQUEST['data_page.php']; ?>
```

But so far, nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to create that variable with the same value (contained in data_page.php) which the form process would provide? And if so... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens currently when you try? Including `<?php $data = $_POST['data']; ?>` shouldn't output anything, that is just an assignment.

Comment: Hi chris88. You're correct, that doesn't output anything. Note: The only thing in the data_page.php page is a two digit number, that's it. Using the form process, I can call that number into the 'data' form field, and then convert it into a variable in the php. But I would like to skip the form step if possible.

Comment: I'm not following what you are doing. `$_POST['data']` is `data_page.php`?

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand what you need then you should turn on output buffering

```
ob_start();

include('data_page.php');
$data = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo $data;
```

or use file_get_contents()

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    ${"data{$i}"} = (is_readable("data_page{$i}.php")) ? file_get_contents("data_page{$i}.php") : '';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately... I have 10 of those variables that need to be created, not just one. So not sure this method would work for me. :/

Comment: Then you can try to use file_get_contents `$data = file_get_contents('data_page.php');`